# Log4J Issue -> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Since last week I'm getting this strange error. without any modification to my code, which is given below.

I went through the SO Answers around same error but most of those refer xml parsing issue, which in my case it's not at all.

Another strange thing is that it's not giving me the stack trace, please read out the comments in the code for the clarity

```
private void initializeLoggerContext(Properties properties) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("initializeLoggerContext : Properties -> " + properties.toString());
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        properties.store(output, null);
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
        Configuration conf = null;
        try {
            ConfigurationSource c = new ConfigurationSource(input);
            //conf = PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(new ConfigurationSource(input));
            ConfigurationFactory conffact = PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getInstance();
            System.out.println("ConfigurationFactory conffact = " + conffact.toString());
            //ERROR : below line prints message on the console as "[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog." with no stack trace
            conf = conffact.getConfiguration(c);
            final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
            ctx.start(conf);
            LOGGER.info("Logging configuration is : {}", ctx);
        } catch(Exception e) {//Note getting called when getting "[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog." on the console
            System.out.println("initializeLoggerContext : Exception is -> ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've created a sample app below with the original input properties but still it's failing with the log4j 2.5. When I tried with the simple property with one key-value pair then also the result was same. Please check the code below :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class EcommLoggingIssueByDeven {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EcommLoggingIssueByDeven.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        String str = "appender.jdbc.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", logger.xmanager.appenderRefs=xmanager"
                + ", appender.remedy.fileName=${remedyfilename}"
                + ", logger.xmanager.additivity=false"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", appender.spring.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", appender.application.fileName=${appfilename}"
                + ", appender.scm.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", appender.scm.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", appender.remedy.filePattern=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename-%i.log.gz"
                + ", logger.jdbc.additivity=false"
                + ", appender.application.type=RollingFile"
                + ", rootLogger.appenderRefs=application"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.policies.size.size=1MB"
                + ", appender.application.strategy.max=10"
                + ", appender.spring.type=RollingFile"
                + ", appender.remedy.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", status=info"
                + ", property.eventFrameworkfilename=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename.log"
                + ", logger.application.level=DEBUG"
                + ", appender.remedy.name=remedy"
                + ", appender.application.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", logger.remedy.name=com.ecommerce.fulfillment.external.remedy"
                + ", logger.jdbc.appenderRef.jdbc.ref=jdbc"
                + ", logger.remedy.level=INFO"
                + ", logger.remedy.appenderRefs=remedy"
                + ", appender.application.filePattern=/log/ecomm-logging/app-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz"
                + ", appender.spring.fileName=${springfilename}"
                + ", logger.eventFramework.appenderRef.eventFramework.ref=eventFramework"
                + ", appender.scm.policies.size.size=1MB"
                + ", logger.eventFramework.name=com.ecommerce.fulfillment.common.eventframework"
                + ", property.appfilename=/log/ecomm-logging/app.log"
                + ", appender.console.layout.pattern=%m%n"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", appender.spring.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", appender.config.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", logger.scm.level=INFO, rootLogger.level=INFO"
                + ", appender.spring.strategy.max=5"
                + ", appender.remedy.policies.size.size=1MB"
                + ", logger.application.appenderRefs=application"
                + ", appender.application.name=application"
                + ", appender.xmanager.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", appender.spring.name=spring"
                + ", appender.jdbc.type=RollingFile"
                + ", appender.jdbc.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", logger.spring.name=org.springframework"
                + ", logger.jdbc.appenderRefs=jdbc"
                + ", logger.scm.name=com.platform"
                + ", appender.scm.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", property.scmfilename=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename.log, logger.spring.appenderRef.spring.ref=spring"
                + ", logger.xmanager.level=INFO"
                + ", appender.xmanager.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", appender.spring.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", appender.scm.filePattern=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename-%i.log.gz"
                + ", appender.jdbc.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", logger.config.level=INFO"
                + ", logger.eventFramework.level=INFO"
                + ", appender.config.strategy.max=5"
                + ", appender.config.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", appender.spring.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", logger.remedy.additivity=false, logger.jdbc.level=INFO"
                + ", appender.scm.type=RollingFile"
                + ", name=PropertiesConfig"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.strategy.max=5"
                + ", appender.scm.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", logger.application.name=com.ecommerce.fulfillment"
                + ", appender.xmanager.fileName=${xmanagerfilename}"
                + ", appender.scm.fileName=${scmfilename}"
                + ", rootLogger.appenderRef.application.ref=application"
                + ", logger.application.additivity=false"
                + ", appender.spring.filePattern=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename-%i.log.gz"
                + ", appender.xmanager.type=RollingFile"
                + ", appender.xmanager.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", appender.jdbc.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.fileName=${eventFrameworkfilename}"
                + ", logger.spring.appenderRefs=spring"
                + ", appender.config.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", appender.jdbc.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", appender.jdbc.name=jdbc, appender.xmanager.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.filePattern=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename-%i.log.gz"
                + ", appender.jdbc.policies.size.size=3MB"
                + ", property.configfilename=/log/ecomm-logging/config1.log"
                + ", appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", appender.config.policies.size.size=1MB"
                + ", appender.spring.policies.size.size=3MB"
                + ", loggers=application,config,eventFramework,jdbc,remedy,scm,spring,xmanager"
                + ", logger.scm.appenderRef.scm.ref=scm"
                + ", appender.config.filePattern=/log/ecomm-logging/config-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz"
                + ", logger.config.appenderRef.config.ref=config"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", appender.scm.name=scm"
                + ", logger.config.appenderRefs=config"
                + ", appender.xmanager.policies.size.size=5MB"
                + ", appender.config.fileName=${configfilename}"
                + ", appender.jdbc.filePattern=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename-%i.log.gz"
                + ", appenders=application,config,eventFramework,jdbc,remedy,scm,spring,xmanager"
                + ", appender.remedy.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", appender.xmanager.name=xmanager"
                + ", property.xmanagerfilename=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename.log"
                + ", logger.spring.level=INFO"
                + ", appender.application.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", logger.xmanager.appenderRef.xmanager.ref=xmanager"
                + ", property.filename=/log/ecomm-logging/test.log"
                + ", logger.eventFramework.appenderRefs=eventFramework"
                + ", appender.application.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", appender.spring.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", logger.spring.additivity=false"
                + ", logger.application.appenderRef.application.ref=application"
                + ", appender.xmanager.filePattern=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename-%i.log.gz"
                + ", logger.scm.appenderRefs=scm"
                + ", appender.scm.strategy.max=5"
                + ", appender.console.type=Console"
                + ", logger.eventFramework.additivity=false"
                + ", appender.application.policies.size.size=5MB"
                + ", appender.jdbc.strategy.max=5"
                + ", logger.remedy.appenderRef.remedy.ref=remedy"
                + ", appender.config.type=RollingFile"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.type=RollingFile"
                + ", appender.jdbc.fileName=${jdbcfilename}"
                + ", logger.scm.additivity=false"
                + ", property.remedyfilename=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename.log"
                + ", appender.application.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", logger.config.name=com.ecommerce.fulfillment.common.configuration"
                + ", logger.xmanager.name=com.ecommerce.fulfillment.common.xmanagerframework"
                + ", appender.config.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", appender.remedy.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", appender.application.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", appender.remedy.layout.type=PatternLayout"
                + ", appender.xmanager.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", appender.config.layout.pattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+0} %p %env %appDetail  [%t] %l %customInfo%msgInfo %n"
                + ", logger.config.additivity=false"
                + ", appender.console.name=STDOUT"
                + ", property.jdbcfilename=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename.log"
                + ", appender.config.name=config"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.name=eventFramework"
                + ", appender.xmanager.strategy.max=5"
                + ", packages=com.ecommerce.logging.plugins"
                + ", logger.jdbc.name=org.springframework.jdbc.core"
                + ", appender.remedy.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy"
                + ", appender.remedy.strategy.max=5"
                + ", appender.remedy.type=RollingFile"
                + ", appender.scm.policies.type=Policies"
                + ", appender.eventFramework.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"
                + ", property.springfilename=${sys:ECOMM_HOME}/logs/filename.log";
        properties.load(new StringBufferInputStream(str));
        System.out.println("Properties -> " + properties.toString());
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        properties.store(output, null);
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
        Configuration conf = null;
        conf = PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(new ConfigurationSource(input));
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        ctx.start(conf);
        LOGGER.info("Logging configuration is : {}", ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your `output.toByteArray()`?

Comment: it's too long almost 190 lines..And nothing suspicious

Comment: @aksappy - I've just updated with the full class code. I've got the solution but still curious to know what went wrong and if this is the limitation of the 2.5 log4j then How come not reported earlier as it's being used by many and this is a common scenario too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfigurationBuilder().setConfigurationSource(source)
    .setRootProperties(properties).build();
Configurator.initialize(config);
```

That is essentially what PropertiesConfigurationFactory does: 
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/properties/PropertiesConfigurationFactory.html

Thinking about this more, the problem may be the call to `LoggerContext.start(Configuration)`. Instead you need to do `Configurator.initialize(config)`.

Comment: ...It worked :) !!!!! 
but still we need to have "LoggerContext.start(Configuration)" as Logger doesn't start action on the provided configuration until and unless we call it explicitly. I tested this and it was building the log files and reflecting the runtime changes after calling start method.
Also just FYI, My code is in 2.5 and the one u've given it's in 2.6.
just replace your last line with code given below :
final LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(config);
ctx.start(conf);

Comment: ...I'm still working on what went wrong with the pure working code of 2.5 .... Please let me know if you were able to find anything on this, Appreciate your response and effort :)

Comment: Glad to hear my answer was useful!